# In Accessibility Mode, I Want To Override The TalkBack For A TextView

Tags: android, accessibility, android-listview, textview

I currently have a ListView and each element of that list consists of at least two TextViews. I'm adding accessibility to my app, so whenever I focus on a certain list element, it reads out the text in each TextView.

Right now, I'm sending it a TalkBack event, but right after it completes it, it reads out the TextViews again. I want it to only complete my TalkBack event and nothing else.

Anyone have a clue how to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you provide the relevant code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, just override [View.dispatchPopulateAccessibilityEvent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#dispatchPopulateAccessibilityEvent%28android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityEvent%29).

From the doc (emphasis mine):

> A typical implementation will call onPopulateAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent) on the this view and then call the dispatchPopulateAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent) on each child.  **Override this method if custom population of the event text content is required.**

Within that method, you can add any text you want to the event in the following manner:

```
public boolean dispatchPopulateAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
    event.getText().add("Hey look!");
    return true;
}
```